# Download gradle plugin on Docker build and use without network during Docker run

Tags: spring-boot, docker, gradle, gradle-plugin

I am working on a Spring boot project where the deployment happens in Kubernetes. The gradle and docker configurations are such that it downloads all the dependencies into the docker image's `libs` directory during `docker build` and get the dependencies from `libs` during `docker run`.

This setting makes the `docker run` (which executes `gradle build` again) successful, even if I cut internet during this process.

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
  id 'java'
}

ext {
    skipDownload = project.hasProperty('skipDownload') ? project.getProperty('skipDownload') as boolean : false
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    if (skipDownload) {
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    } else {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

dependencies {
  if (skipDownload) {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation fileTree(dir: 'testlibs', include: ['*.jar'])
  } else {
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.6.3'
  }
}

task getDeps(type: Copy) {
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
    from configurations.compileClasspath into "libs/"
    from configurations.runtimeClasspath into "libs/"
}

task getTestDeps(type: Copy) {
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
    from configurations.testCompileClasspath into "testlibs/"
    from configurations.testRuntimeClasspath into "testlibs/"
}
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM gradle:7.3-jdk11
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN gradle --no-daemon test getDeps getTestDeps
CMD ["sh", "gradle bootRun"] // for this testing I will later change to gradle build during docker run command
```

**Docker build**

```
docker build -t service-test .
```

**Docker run** - AFTER CUTTING THE INTERNET

```
docker run --rm -it service-test gradle build -PskipDownload=true
```

These steps has been successful as expected. But when I add another plugin,as shown below, to support `gradle booRun` the step "Docker run - AFTER CUTTING THE INTERNET" is failing with the following error.

```
plugins {
  id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.3'
  id 'java'
}
```

> Plugin [id: 'org.springframework.boot', version: '2.6.3'] was not
> found in any of the following sources:
>
> - Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
> - Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.springframework.boot:org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin:2.6.3')
>   Searched in the following repositories:
>   Gradle Central Plugin Repository

Please direct me to fix this issue. I need to run the container offline.

Answer (score 2):

The issue you have is that you override only the dependency repository, not the plugin repository. These are handled separately.
In the case of the java plugin, this is part of gradles core plugins and is available locally through gradle itself.

Third-party plugins like spring need to be downloaded from a plugin repository. By default, this is the Gradle plugin repository. You can override this in a settings.gradle file.

**For example:**

```java
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'lib'
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

But you probably don't even have to change this.
You could just download the plugins in your first (online) build cycle and then copy the gradle cache inside the docker. You should also use the `--offline` flag for your second build cycle to indicate that no network access is allowed.

The default cache location is `~/.gradle/caches/`. In my case, all dependencies (including plugins) cached by gradle were under `~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/`.

Some helpful links:
[Plugin Management](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugin_management)
[Plugin vs. Build Repos](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec:plugin-vs-build-repos)
[Repository Types](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec:repository-types)
[Execution Options (--offline)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_execution_options)
[sync gradle dependencies to local maven reposity](https://nishtahir.com/caching-gradle-build-dependencies-to-a-local-maven-repository/)

Comment: Thanks for checking out. You have suggested two changes. 

1) `flatDir{dirs 'lib'}`. But how the plugins are stored into "libs" during docker build? 

2) Gradle cache copying. But during docker build, after `RUN gradle...` command I put an `RUN ls ~/.gradle`, but the directory was not found. I think inside docker intermediate container, it's not being cached.

Comment: For approach 2) maybe try running your build commands step by step inside your container first. It has to download these dependencies, else you would not be able to build your project. Perhaps the default cache path is a different one in your docker image, or it clears it by default right after your build is complete. 

Try launching your docker with your project inside, install gradle(if absent) and build your project. You can use `--gradle-user-home /path/to/folder` to set the gradle home to a specific folder for a specific execution. The folder paths have to be the same on both systems.

Comment: Approach 1) can be used if you push your dependencies to a local maven or something similar. Or have some sort of folder structure with you dependencies in it (other project, or whatever). I guess it is more convoluted than just copying gradles cache. But It is still an option to use a local maven repo instead of going the gradle way. For that, you could just define maven as your repository (for both phases) and just copy the maven repo. This should essentially work the same as approach 2.

Comment: Regarding approach 1) I have found the following blog post: https://nishtahir.com/caching-gradle-build-dependencies-to-a-local-maven-repository/